# Why is a sequence named hibernate_sequence being created with JPA using Hibernate with the Oracle 10g dialect?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa, oracle10g

All my entities use this type of `@Id`

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "MYENTITY_SEQ")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "MYENTITY_SEQ", sequenceName = "MYENTITY_SEQ")
@Column(name = "MYENTITY", nullable = false)
private Long id;
```

or

```
@Id
@Column(name = "MYENTITY")
```

I find that an Oracle sequence named `hibernate_sequence` is always created. Why is this so? And how can I avoid this?

I am using JPA1 with Hibernate 3 and the Oracle 10g dialect.

Comment: Are you sure you do not have any @Entity's id annotated with @GeneratedValue() without no attribute declared ???

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I suspect it's because i am using Hibernate Envers as i've double checked my entities and all of them have the correct @Id mappings.

Comment: and what was the solution for it?

Answer (score 10):

The HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE is used with REVINFO-entity for creating revision numbers. If you want to use different sequence you should create your custom revision entity.

Help with that:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/envers/3.5/reference/en-US/html/revisionlog.html

Answer (score 4):

I see the following code in `org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator`:

```
public void configure(Type type, Properties params, Dialect dialect) throws MappingException {
    ObjectNameNormalizer normalizer = ( ObjectNameNormalizer ) params.get( IDENTIFIER_NORMALIZER );
    sequenceName = normalizer.normalizeIdentifierQuoting(
            PropertiesHelper.getString( SEQUENCE, params, "hibernate_sequence" )
    );
    parameters = params.getProperty( PARAMETERS );

    if ( sequenceName.indexOf( '.' ) < 0 ) {
        final String schemaName = normalizer.normalizeIdentifierQuoting( params.getProperty( SCHEMA ) );
        final String catalogName = normalizer.normalizeIdentifierQuoting( params.getProperty( CATALOG ) );
        sequenceName = Table.qualify(
                dialect.quote( catalogName ),
                dialect.quote( schemaName ),
                dialect.quote( sequenceName )
        );
    }
    else {
        // if already qualified there is not much we can do in a portable manner so we pass it
        // through and assume the user has set up the name correctly.
    }

    this.identifierType = type;
    sql = dialect.getSequenceNextValString( sequenceName );
}
```

Where the third parameter of `PropertiesHelper.getString(String, Properties, String)` is the default property value.

So I'm tempted to say that, somewhere, you have an `Id` not "properly" annotated. Maybe you should perform a little debugging session.