# Override default sequence name in Grails

Tags: grails

How can I rename `HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE`?  Methods for generating one sequence per table (and giving specific names to those sequences) are well-documented, but that's not what I'm looking for.

I don't mind having one sequence shared by all domain classes. I just need to give it an application-specific name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be an open feature / enhancement request in the Hibernate JIRA to make this globally configurable:  [Make the default sequence name globally configurable](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-2637).  I believe, as a workaround, you would have to set the 'generator' attribute to the same name for all domain classes (defaults to hibernate_sequence) for every @Id field.  See [oracle sequence created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058251/why-is-an-oracle-sequence-named-hibernate-sequence-being-created-with-jpa-using-h).

As you hinted in your question, there might be a way to do this by subclassing your database dialect - as many have suggested for a sequence-per-table approach.

See [id generator and DRY principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564491/does-overloading-grails-static-mapping-property-to-bolt-on-database-objects-vio)

Comment: I seem to have had success extending org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator and the dialect.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code I used to set the sequence name.

First, the SequenceGenerator:

```
package com.foo;

import java.util.Properties;

import org.hibernate.MappingException;
import org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect;
import org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator;
import org.hibernate.type.Type;

public class TableNameSequenceGenerator extends SequenceGenerator {

    public static final String CUSTOM_SEQUENCE_NAME = "MYAPP_SEQUENCE"

    public void configure(Type type, Properties params, Dialect dialect) throws MappingException {
        if(params.getProperty(SEQUENCE) == null || params.getProperty(SEQUENCE).length() == 0) {
            String seqName = CUSTOM_SEQUENCE_NAME;
            params.setProperty(SEQUENCE, seqName);               
        }
        super.configure(type, params, dialect);
    }

}
```

Next, the OracleDialect:

```
package com.foo;

import org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect;

public class MyAppOracleDialect extends Oracle10gDialect {
    public Class getNativeIdentifierGeneratorClass() {
        return TableNameSequenceGenerator.class;
    }
}
```

Last, DataSource.groovy needs to know about the dialect:

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
    // username, password....
    dialect='com.foo.MyAppOracleDialect'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Renaming the sequence is IMHO not directly possible but you might customize the identity as described on http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20(GORM).html#5.5.2.4%20Custom%20Database%20Identity to generator:'native'. See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id-generator for details.