# How do I keep Grails from generating the default Hibernate_sequence during dbCreate?

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, grails, groovy

In each of my domains I have defined a custom sequence inside the static mapping closure:

```
static mapping = {
    version false
    id generator:'sequence', params:[sequence:'MY_SEQ']   
}
```

When I create the database, the MY_SEQ sequence is there, however grails also still makes a default hibernate_sequence. How do I get grails to not make the default, and be certain that it is using my custom sequence? Is this common for Grails to generate a default even though it won't get used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is common and it comes from Hibernate by default, it's not a grails' thing. There's even a [JIRA](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-2637) open for that, but still unresolved.

You could try to extend the dialect though! You can find a code that is kinda same thing you want in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412716/override-default-sequence-name-in-grails?lq=1).

About being sure if the table is using the specified sequence, it should, given the way you did it.

Comment: Great, thanks! I am going to test it out as is, and if I find there is issues, then I will look into the dialect.