# Hibernate - change default sequence table name

Tags: hibernate, orm

I'm wondering if I can change the default name of the default table for sequences 'hibernate_sequences'? I don't want to specify a sequence generator each time I use one but would rather prefer to change the default name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `@TableGenerator` annotation to give customized name along with `@GeneratedValue` annotation.

Comment: is it possible to change the name globally, instead of one per ID?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412716/override-default-sequence-name-in-grails)

Comment: thanks, it slipped through my fingers because it's not tagged with hibernate :(. So there is no way to simply change the default.